# Facebook load the canvas in the tab with some accounts

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm experiencing a weird thing in an apps I'm developping.

The tab is loading the canvas. In the apps parameter I've filled the right path to both canvas and tabs.

Here is the apache log for the app admina account while loading the tab:

```
172.16.109.9 - - [01/Sep/2011:15:48:30 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1593 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.865.0 Safari/535.2"
```

I tried with another account, tester of the apps, he load the right file. Here is the apache log :

```
172.16.109.9 - - [01/Sep/2011:15:52:59 +0200] "POST /tab HTTP/1.1" 200 1314 "_https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.1"
```

Is this a known Facebook glitch ?

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "loading the canvas"?
Is the user redirected to your canvas version or the canvas content is shown inside the page tab, instead of the tab content?

There are some things that come into my mind, but I would like to know what is the problem exactly

Comment: The canvas is loaded within the tab. 

The weird thing is, as you can see in the apache log, it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: Do you have a different url for the canvas and the tab? I'm asking because I use the same url, and redirect the user to the correct version based on the  signed_request. Also, I presume you don't use any .htaccess or redirect settings that might cause this, right? Thing is, there are so many things that could be wrong with your script, that you have to be sure it's not something else causing it. If you use 2 different simple html files for the canvas and the tab, do you still get this strange behavior?

Comment: No we use two different URLs and two different HTML files. The / of the apps contains the canvas and the /tab contains, obviously, the tab. And half the time it loads the canvas.